# What is == mechanism in Scala?

Tags: scala

Just would like to get some detail on how scala `==` works when comparing two strings.

How does object comaparision works in scala?

Comment: In Scala you compare two Strings with the == operator. What do you want to know about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

== in Scala is equivalent to `.equals()` in Java

Comment: Except for primitive types when it's equivalent to `==`.

Comment: No, it's not equivalent to `.equals()`. It means value equality on primitive types and on reference types it's equivalent to `Objects.equals(a, b)` (`null` handling!)

Comment: @soulcheck No, since there are cases where `==` on primitives and `.equals()` differ on boxed types (e.g. `NaN == NaN`, `-0 == +0`) and in these cases you can see Scala `==` behaves like primitive `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to build on [Gizmo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23423088/926710), whilst `==` in Java or C# is an operator that checks for reference equality, in Scala it is a method that checks for value equality. `==` should be used when you want to check whether two Strings (or any two values in general) have the same value.

`==` is declared on the `Any` supertype as a final method. Internally it uses the `equals` method, also declared in `Any` but as a non-final method. When you want to change how `==` behaves for a type, you do this by overriding `equals`:

```
override def equals(that: Any) : Boolean = {
  ...
}

// You probably would want to override this too
override def hashCode = ...
```

Comment: A word of caution: Implementing `equals` correctly is not simple. Before you write a custom `equals` my stock advice is to read chapter 28 of Programming in Scala and then, (appealing to the first rule of program optimization … http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization) don't!

Answer (score 0):

In Scala everything is an object, as @avik mentioned `==` internally uses `equals` which is already defined for String class. If you want to properly use `==` for your own class - override `equals`. If you want to compare references - use `eq`. From docs:

The expression `x == that` is equivalent to

`if (x eq null) that eq null 
 else x.equals(that)`